# Python: Extract field values into new columns, write to Excel

Tags: python, regex, pandas, csv

I am reading a CSV file and intend to write to an Excel file.  The CSV file only has two columns, however I want to use regex to extract column data and create new columns, before writing to Excel.

CSV file: `test.csv`

```
name, file_info
test, c:\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder2\example.xls | history 12345 at 2020-01-01
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv',mode='r') as testFile
     reader = csv.DictReader(testFile, delimiter=',')
     for row in reader:
          ### This is where i assume i need to perform the regex operation on the current row
```

I want to extract the filename (`example.xlsx`), history (`12345`) and date (`2020-01-01`) as columns in an Excel file.

I have a tested regex successfully

```
"\\([^\\|]*)\s*\|\"
```

I am sure there are multiple ways to do this.  Would Pandas be better?  I am able to simply read and write the file to excel by:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df.to_excel('text.xlsx)
```

I don't have any experience with Pandas so not sure how to perform the operations I want with regex and tie it all together.

The end product is an excel spreadsheet with five (5) columns

`name | path | file | history | date`

Comment: Using Pandas, have a look at using the df[['newcol1', 'newcol2']] = DataFrame.loc['colname'].str.extract(REGEX) logic.  Obviously with your fields and regex pattern.  This will extract **named regex groups** into new columns of you DataFrame.  It's a bit awesome.

Comment: May we have some example rows from you CSV please?

Comment: _I don't have any experience with Pandas so not sure how to perform the operations i want with regex and tie it all together._ **Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials, or documentation**, which are what you need. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Here's more of the CSV

Comment: name, file_info
test1,c:\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder2\example1.xls | history 12345 at 2020-01-01
test2,c:\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder2\example2.xls | history 24687 at 2020-01-12
test3,c:\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder2\example3.xls | history 33445 at 2020-01-13
test4,c:\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder2\example4.xls | history 55664 at 2020-01-14

Comment: Thanks @S3DEV  I will try your Pandas example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a technique which uses Pandas `df['column'].str.extract()` function.

You can pass a compiled (or non-compiled) regex string into the `extract()` function.  This will use the named groups in the expression and extract those groups into columns by the same name.

#### Sample Data:

```
name,file_info
test1,c:\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder2\example1.xls | history 12345 at 2020-01-01
test2,c:\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder2\example2.xls | history 24687 at 2020-01-12
test3,c:\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder2\example3.xls | history 33445 at 2020-01-13
test4,c:\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder2\example4.xls | history 55664 at 2020-01-14
```

#### The Code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import re

# Define constants
COLS = ['name', 'path', 'file', 'history', 'date']
PATH = './test.csv'
PATH_XL = './test.xlsx'
RE_EXP = re.compile(r'^'
                    '(?P<path>.*)\|\shistory\s'
                    '(?P<history>\d+)\sat\s'
                    '(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})$',
                    re.IGNORECASE)

# Read CSV file.
df = pd.read_csv(PATH)
# Create new columns using named regex groups.
df[['path', 'history', 'date']] = df['file_info'].str.extract(RE_EXP)
# Extract the filename from the path using a built-in function.
df['file'] = df['path'].apply(os.path.basename)
# Convert date to datetime format.
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.date
# Subset DataFrame to only the columns we require.
df = df[COLS]
# Write results to Excel.
df.to_excel(PATH_XL, index=False)
```

#### Excel Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I created a test file to test your code and get mutliple exceptions.  The first is a KeyError: 'file_info' on line 18: "df[['path', 'history', 'date']] = df['file_info'].str.extract(RE_EXP)"

Comment: Ok.  Make sure that 1) your column names are **name** and **file_info**, and 2) that there are **no leading/training spaces**.  So your header must be: `name,file_info`.

Comment: OK, I think i have it working.  One thing.  How to I remove the time in the date format?  I just want '2020-01-01'

Comment: Just add `.dt.date` to the end of the datetime conversion.  This converts the `Series` to a `datetime` object and the `.date` attribute retrieves only the date.  See the edited answer.  Please accept the answer if this is working for you.  Thanks!

Comment: It's been a while since you helped me with my solution.  I am revisiting this code and am getting an error on the line `df['file'] = df['path'].apply(os.path.basename)`  The error i get is **TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not float**.  I am not sure if it is related to now using Python 3.7 but code is not working for me now.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Without seeing the data causing the error, it’s difficult to say for sure.  The error mentions float; therefore I’d presume not all values in the `path` column are strings.  Maybe a `NaN` value is present?  Ensure *all* values in the column are strings (`str` or `object`) and try again.